# Picture Box Scroll

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a scenario where I want to use 'n' number of picture boxes to display 'm' number of images (in a series), where 'm' will be always greater than 'n'.

Say 3 picture boxes and 15 images. At the beginning I'd only want to load 3 images (1,2 and 3). Later when scrolled down (i.e when picture box 1 is completely out of view), it would load next set of images like (2,3 and 4) but using the same number of picture boxes previously added. When scrolled up, it would load the images (1,2 and 3).

Currently I have a scrollable panel (with AutoScroll property set to true) and added the picture boxes and images. But I am not sure how to handle the scroll event to swap the images.

Thanks

Comment: Do not use the standard AutoScroll. Add a separate scrollbar and respond to the scroll/value changed events.

Comment: *"to swap the images"* - why do you want to swap anything?

Comment: @Sinatr When scrolled down, I want picture box 1 to display image 2 and picture box 2 to display image 3 and so on. Just to show make it look like it's actually scrolling.

Comment: That's complicated (to simulate scrolling while doing some swapping). Rather look into *data virtualization* (e.g. this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42229/Virtual-Mode-ListView)). In simplest approach: add 15 empty `PictureBox`'es to `Panel` and handle panel's `Scroll` event to actually set their `Image` property. You can use placeholder image and  Image *caching* can occurs in other thread. In such scenario you don't need to *simulate scrolling*, nor swap anything (unload invisible `PictureBox` images using some cache policy is a good idea to avoid OOM though).

Comment: @Sinatr I thought about it, but 15 isn't the actual number, it can be anything like 100 or 1000, the actual idea is something like an infinite scroll but with consuming less memory by using static number of picture boxes. I tried swapping it in scroll event, but the issue for me is it's hard to maintain the indices and scroll position correctly.

Comment: You are implementing a VirtualizingStackPanel. If possible you might want to swap to WPF instead of Winforms and use what is already there. See: http://classpattern.com/smooth-scrolling-with-virtualization-wpf-list.html#.WTpv6OuGNGE

Comment: @Sinatr Unfortunately, it's part of a big Winforms project.

Comment: Any other idea on how to implement it in winforms?